# Updating a variable from a file in loop

Tags: c++, file, batch-file, while-loop

- Sorry for my grammar\spelling. I'm Romanian.
- I am using Code::Blocks to edit in C++ and Notepad to edit in Batch.

I can't find a better title for this.

I'm trying to use this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <string>
#include "G:\other.h"
using namespace std;
char message[500],from[20];
int interm;
int main()
{
    ofstream wait1("errorlevel.f"); wait1<<0; wait1.close();
    fstream wait2("errorlevel.f",ios::in); wait2>>interm;
    cout<<"Another window is waiting for you...";
    system("start options_load-new.bat");
    while (interm==0) { wait2>>interm; Sleep(10); }
    st();
    //and program continues...
}
```

where `st();` function is declared in `other.h` as

```
void st()
{
    system("cls");
}
```

and the options_load-new.bat file is this:

```
@echo off
echo What do you want to do?
echo [L] Load a pre-made message
echo [N] Make a new one
choice /c ln
echo %errorlevel% > errorlevel.f
exit
```

but -

When I run the program, is opens, starts the .bat file, that file sets `errorlevel.f` to 1 or 2, and closes. After that, the main program remains to `Another windws is waiting for you...` without any action.

What should I do to make the main program continue his operations?

Comment: Remove `start` from the `system` call because it's a launcher that immediately exits after executing the batch file. I'm not sure it'll be sufficient for your program to function correctly, thus not posting it as an answer.

Comment: You are trying to read into a `int`, probably where there is not a suitable value at that point in the file, which would cause you to get stuck in the loop. You need to check the read succeeded immediately after the read. Normally you would do something like `while(wait2>>interm) { // do stuff }`.

Comment: wOxxOm, you are the best! I didn't have that idea... I knew if I remove the `start` from the `system` call it will run in the main program's console... Now BoBTFish, just for knowledge, how I use `while (wait2>>interm)`?